# List IIS website

Tags: iis, service, passwords, windows-server-2003

As part of a project I am working on ..I am in need of achieving following task.Can anyone throw some ideas ..

I am required to document the website , service account used by website , password for service account from IIS 6.0. The server is running windows 2003. Is there any kind of dos command or any script which can list all the above information for me ?. I need to document for 15-20 servers and on each server 15-18 websites are running. So instead documenting manually , I am thinking of using/writing script. Can anyone help by putting me in right direction ...?

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can use adsutil.vbs that is included as part of IIS 6 installation for the most part of your requirements. Its just been too long a time for me to remember the exact commands in IIS 6.

And if your environment allows then you can simply "psexec" your script or batch file to all 15 servers.

Hope this helps.